# Can`t first push to docker based gitlab server

Tags: git, docker, gitlab

My `gitlab` server running on `docker` on `Centos7` machine.
I tried push exist repo to gitlab:

`git remote rename origin old-origin`

`git remote add origin http://myhost/user/project.git`

`git push -u origin --all`

`Username for 'myhost': user`

`Password for 'myhost':`

`fatal: Authentication failed for ' http://myhost/user/project.git'`

**I tried server and gitlab credentials.**

docker started with command:

`docker run -p 80:80 -p 2222:22 -p 443:443 -d f77dd1b93b45`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Try to login through the web UI to ensure that you are typing the correct password
- Check if Two-Factor Authentication is enabled if yes then you need to generate a [personal access token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html) to use it instead of username and password.

  > You can create as many personal access tokens as you like from your GitLab profile.
  >
  > - Log in to your GitLab account.
  > - Go to your **Profile settings**.
  > - Go to **Access tokens**.
  > - Choose a name and optionally an expiry date for the token.
  > - Choose the [desired scopes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html#limiting-scopes-of-a-personal-access-token).
  > - Click on **Create personal access token**.
  > - Save the personal access token somewhere safe. Once you leave or refresh the page, you won’t be able to access it again.